# Testing dispatch of a toast event from a LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am unable to test for the right dispatch of an event after an error returned from a mocked wire service.

This is the component

```
import { api, LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import myMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MyController.MyMethod";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

  @api recordId = "who-cares";

  @track
  data;

  @wire(myMethod, { myObjId: "$recordId" })
  wiredRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.data = data;
    } else {
      if (error) {
        let errorMessage = "Unknown error";

        if (Array.isArray(error.body.message)) {
          errorMessage = error.body.message.map((e) => e.message).join(", ");
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === "string") {
          errorMessage = error.body.message;
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error when invoking the Controller API",
            message: errorMessage,
            variant: "error",
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the test:

```
import MyComponent from "c/myComponent";
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest";
import myMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MyController.MyMethod";
import { ShowToastEventName } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { createElement } from "lwc";

const mockMyMethod = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(
  myMethod
);

const mockErrorResponse = require("./data/errorResponse.json");

describe("My Component", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
  });
  
  it("should correctly show a toast when the API returns an error", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-my-component", {
      is: MyComponent,
    });
    const handler = jest.fn();
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.addEventListener(ShowToastEventName, handler);
    myMethod.error(
      mockErrorResponse.body,
      mockErrorResponse.status
    );
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();     
    });
  });
});
```

I do not see anything wrong in my test, is there a problem with testing dispatching of events from inside the component?

Comment: Try adding the event listener to the document, not the LWC itself. Remember to remove it again afterwards.

Comment: What are the contents of the errorResponse.json?

Comment: {
    "status": 500,
    "body": {
        "message": [
            {
                "message": "Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'myId' of type 'Id'"
            }
        ]
    },
    "headers": {}
}

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `registerLdsTestWireAdapter` instead of `registerApexTestWireAdapter` for your test, and also need to fire the error,so you're missing this line

```js
mockMyMethod.error(mockErrorResponse);

//can also have no arguments and sfdx-lwc-jest adds a default message
mockMyMethod.error();
```

See the [Apex Wire Adapter Example](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/write-a-jest-test-for-wire-service)

Regarding your follow-up about the event detail being empty. Looking at the [sfdx-lwc-jest source](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-stubs/platformShowToastEvent/platformShowToastEvent.js), the ShowToastEvent is stubbed in a way that the event detail doesn't get set.

You can make your own custom stub at the project level so that it adds the toast as event.detail. Here is [an example in the lwc-recipes repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/platformShowToastEvent.js). Be aware that for this to work you also need to update your projects jest config so that the module is resolved to your custom stub. See moduleNameMapper in [the lwc-recipes jest.config.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/jest.config.js)

Comment: Should I switch the import or instead of using .error using .emit on the registerLdsTestWireAdapter? Because I tried switching the import to registerApexTestWireAdapter and my test stil fail

Comment: This works except that the custom event detail is null :(

Comment: @Edmondo1984 you are right you should use .error(). I have updated my answer, and also provided a workaround for your issue of the event detail not being set.